# api-platform odm iri reference won't be converted into objects in json

Tags: php, mongodb, document, api-platform.com, doctrine-odm

I want to create a model like this.

```
{
  "id": 7653,
  "name": "Vortl 123",
   "category": [
    {
      "name": "Electronic",
      "url": "electronic",
      "id": 1
    }, {
      "name": "Phone",
      "url": "phone",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "Mobile Phone",
      "url": "mobile-phone",
      "id": 3
    }
}
```

I created documents with using doctrine odm references. Codes are these.

This is product class.

```
/**
 * @ApiResource
 *
 * @Document
 */
class Product
{

    /**
     * @ODM\Id(strategy="INCREMENT", type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    public $name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ODM\ReferenceMany(targetDocument=Category::class, inversedBy="product", cascade={"persist"}, storeAs="id")
     */
    public $categories;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * @param Category $category
     */
    public function addCategory(Category $category): void
    {
        $this->categories->add($category);
    }

    public function removeCategory(Category $category): void
    {

        $category->product = null;
        $this->categories->removeElement($category);
    }
```

and my category class is.

```
/**
 * @ApiResource
 *
 * @ODM\Document
 */
class Category
{

    /**
     * @ODM\Id(strategy="INCREMENT", type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument=Product::class, mappedBy="categories", storeAs="id")
     */
    public $product;


    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="string")
     */
    private $url;


    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId($id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }




    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $name
     */
    public function setName($name): void
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->url;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $url
     */
    public function setUrl($url): void
    {
        $this->url = $url;
    }


}
```

It works correct. When I can post category and get them. Then I post product and add categories to product via iri reference. The problem is I see the categories id instead of categories object like this.

```
{
    "@context": "/api/contexts/Product",
    "@id": "/api/products/17",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "Product17",
    "categories": [
        "/api/categories/1",
        "/api/categories/2",
        "/api/categories/3"
    ]
}
```

I create category with post method then I create product with post method. To add category to product, I'm using iri reference like /api/categories/1 in the post method of product.

I don't understand why it is showing with iri reference? I want object of those iri references in the example that I want. Can anyone help me?

Comment: To do this, simply add serialization and deserialization groups to each entity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must add at minimum one group `normalizationContext`:

```
<?php

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups" = {"product:read"}}
 * )
 *
 * @Document
 */
class Product
{

    /**
     * @ODM\Id(strategy="INCREMENT", type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Groups({"product:read"})
     */
    public $name;

    // ...
}
```

and `Category`:

```
<?php

/**
 * @ApiResource
 *
 * @Document
 */
class Category
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Groups({"product:read"})
     */
    public $name;

    // ...
}
```

After that you should see `Category`'s objects with property `$name`

Comment: Yes, It's the best way to do

Comment: Sorry, I'm new. I didn't get the logic. why you used group annotation in product name? The only problem I have is category collection. Category collection still comes with iri reference instead of object while I'm doing it just like you did.

Comment: I think you need to read the documentation https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#embedding-relations. In short, you need to add the same group to “Product” (for all operations or one operation) and to “Category” in all the properties that you want to see in the answer.

Comment: Oh the documentation and your answers helped me to understand and solve. Thank you.